# Is there a verbose logging mode for pickle.dumps()?

Tags: python, pickle

Im trying to encode about 25000 images into a pickle file using the following code

```
f = open("dataset_encoding.pickle", "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(sampleDataset))
f.close()
```

Python consumes a lot of time executing this function on my PC, is there a verbose logging option for `pickle.dumps()` so I can know that it is still running?

I couldn't find anything [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Do you want to log to stdout or a log file?

Comment: @medic17 I'd prefer stdout, but if there is a way to log into a text file, please enlighten me.

Comment: what data type is the sample data set in python? You need it to both file and stdout correct?

Comment: There's no logging or printing code in the module, so it's a no.

Comment: You cloud still print to stdout `x file encoded using a for loop

Comment: @medic17 Its a list of NumPy arrays. Specifically with lengths 10000, 2500, 10000, 2500. So totally amounting to 25000. All images have RGB layers.

Comment: Why don't you store one image after the other? ``pickle`` allows dumping several objects into the same file, one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I was trying to pickle a list of length 4. To reduce the memory usage per pickle file, I decided to save my list into 4 different pickles. Following is the code I used to print a ProgressBar while the pickling completes :

```
import pickle

def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█', printEnd = "\r"):
"""
Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
@params:
    iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
    total      - Required  : total iterations (Int)
    prefix    - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
    suffix    - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
    decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
    length    - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
    fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    printEnd    - Optional  : end character (e.g. "\r", "\r\n") (Str)
"""
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = printEnd)
    if iteration == total: 
        print() 

def verbosePickle(data_list, filename, prefix_text):
    print("sampleDataset["+str(index)+"] Length :"+str(len(sample)))
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(len(data_list), f)
        printProgressBar(0, len(data_list)-1, prefix = prefix_text, suffix = "Complete", length = 50)
        for data_index, data in enumerate(data_list):
            printProgressBar(data_index, len(data_list)-1, prefix = prefix_text, suffix = "Complete", length = 50)
            pickle.dump(data, f)

for index, sample in enumerate(sampleDataset):
    print("Saving Pickle Files")
    verbosePickle(sample, "sampleDataset"+index+".pickle", "Saving pickle "+index+" :")
```

Standard Output :

> Saving pickle 0 :
>   |█████████████████████-----------------------------| 44.0% Complete